# How to use ggplotly() with "large" data and geom_tile()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I try to visualise a status of Thing every minute per week in R. Plotly has problems with the ggplot - it can't render it. Do you have some tip for a workaround?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)   

data <- tibble(ts = seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-07 00:00:00", tz="GMT"), 
                        length.out=10080, by='1 min'),
               status = sample(x = c("Status A", "Status B", "Status C"), 
                               prob = c(.6, .3, .1),
                               size = 10080, 
                               replace = TRUE)
) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(date = lubridate::as_date(ts)) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(hm = format(ts, "%H:%M")) |> 
  dplyr::select(-ts)


gg_heatmap <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = data, ggplot2::aes(x = date, y = hm, fill = status)) +
  ggplot2::geom_raster()

gg_heatmap
```

[image]

```
plotly::ggplotly(gg_heatmap) # That doesn't work anymore!
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use heatmaply's library

Answer (score 1):

Please summarize your data or try to do other visualizations. Ggplotly has to build 10.080 reactive fields that it's heavy.

I've tried to do your plot with `heatmaply`, the problem is that you have to change *status* in a numeric variable and mutate your data as a matrix.

You have to wait a time for rendering but works.

```r
install.packages("heatmaply")
library(heatmaply)

data %>% 
  mutate(status = sapply(data$status, function(x) switch(x,
                                                         "Status A" = 1,
                                                         "Status B" = 2,
                                                         "Status C" = 3))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = status) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  tibble::column_to_rownames("hm") %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  heatmaply(., 
            dendrogram = "none",
            xlab = "", ylab = "", 
            main = "",
            scale = "none",
            titleX = FALSE,
            hide_colorbar = TRUE,
            branches_lwd = 0.1,
            label_names = c("Time: ", "Date: ", "Status֫: "),
            fontsize_row = 5, fontsize_col = 5,
            labCol = colnames(mat),
            labRow = rownames(mat)
  )
```

[image: screenshot of plot]

[image: zoom of plot]

Comment: Hey @Erik De Luca,
thanks for your answer. I really need a "week overview" for the thing status in a shiny app. The users can use the hoover to get some extra information besides date/time and status then. I already aggregated the information from seconds to minutes. Going futher to 5min or so is not really an option. I - on the other side - are not forced too use geom_tile() or even plotly. Are there other options?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know other solutions. The problem is that plotly will create 10.080 tiles on HTML and this is very heavy. I think that you have to look for a different way to visualize the data. For example, you could visualize 10.080 tiles only with ggplot and then the user could focus on one day or one hour by different days and this one doing with plotly.